# ifelse error, comparing a list value to a defined value

Tags: r

I am learning R as a beginner and stuck with some error messages.
The scenario is that "clean data" from a student score list--
Here I am trying to set any score greater than 100 to be a missing value. Also using
`stringr::str_replace`, replace any *beginning* `~` in the
score, for example, "~56", with an empty string.

My code:

```
scorelist %>% ifelse(score>100, NA)

scorelist%>% stringr::str_replace(score,pattern="~",replacement=" ")
```

but keep getting error message in

> Error in ifelse(.,score > 100, NA) : 'list' object cannot be coerced
>   to type 'logical'.

How should I fix my code? Thanks a lot!sorry for the beginner's question.

Comment: `scorelist %>% mutate(score = ifelse(score>100, NA, score))`

Comment: And `pattern="^~.*"`

Comment: I appreciate the help! I figured it out now.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
scorelist %>%
       mutate(score = replace(score, score > 100, NA))
```

Comment: appreciate the help!